# Create folders in Document Center

Tags: document, folder

I have a document center site. I see I can upload file but I cannot organize them in folders ?

Can I also create folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create folders inside your "Document" document library or your default document library. While uploading you can set the destination folder of your file.